# Can I safely use Rx in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, system.reactive

We've used Rx successfully in a number of projects previously and love how the Reactive patterns compartmentalize responsibilities and dependencies.  We feel that there's a strong correlation between the event stream driven philosophy of Rx and ServiceStack's message-based approach.

I was wondering whether anybody has had a crack at using Rx with ServiceStack and could share some of their experiences... Specifically I'm interested in:

- At what point did you pass requests into the Rx pipeline?
- Did you create new Rx Observables every request?
- How did you handle dealing with using request scoped objects like db connections, transactionality etc inside your Observables?

Apologies in advance if this is too broad, but I'm interested in the implementation details and guidance anyone can offer.

Comment: ServiceStack doesn't really have anything to do with this, it's just executes your Service in an ASP.NET HttpHandler, a better question would be "Can I safely use Rx in ASP.NET?". But I'd strongly recommend avoiding using Request Scoped dependencies which are tied to the HTTP request context, only use Singleton (default) or `ReuseScope.None` dependencies instead.

Comment: That does avoid a lot of headaches. We actually use the multi-tenancy feature in ServiceStack which chooses a Db based on the Request, so we can't make everything ReuseScope.None. For stuff like this we're passing the originating Request along the event stream so we can use it to resolve instances as needed. Do you see any problems with this?

Comment: Our Observables are singletons btw.